# Is it possible to choose between two strings.xml files?

Tags: android, xml

I am currently working on an Android App, and have been for about six weeks. I just found out that it will also need to be run in a different language. All of my string resources are saved in the `strings.xml` file.

What I was wondering, was if I could make a separate file, something like `strings2.xml`, and depending on what the user chooses, the program will choose either `strings.xml or strings2.xml` for all of the string references.

This would be in my layout file, `main.xml`.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/more_parametersButton"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="@string/more_parameters" />
```

Then I would have 2 separate string files.
strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <string name="more_parameters">More Parameters</string>
</resources>
```

and strings2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<resources>
    <string name="more_parameters">Mais Parâmetros</string>
</resources>
```

It seems like this won't be possible, but if it is, I'd appreciate the info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it looks like you are simply trying to internationalize your app. android of course has a well-defined facility for this. create locale-specific values folders under `res` as

```
res/values-<locale>/strings.xml
```

and populate this file with the values according to the locale. for example,

```
res/values-fr_FR/strings.xml
```

for details, read the [Android Localization](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html) page on the developer site.

Answer (score 2):

you can switch language manually..

```
  String[] array={"English","Deutsch"};
                Locale locale = new Locale(array[0]);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
                Configuration config = new Configuration();
                config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

but for this you need res/values-de/strings.xml for Deutsch [localization.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html)

Answer (score 2):

It can be done in Android very easily,

Not only String.xml(for different languages), you can also use same layouts.xml, drawables(for different screen sizes), You just need to name your res/folder-name folder accordingly, Mr Blattman already answered in detail.